# Unable to run Drools Android serialized-kbase example in Android N devices

Tags: android, drools, dexclassloader

I have been able to run the drools serialized-kbase example (https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/6.5.0.Final/drools-examples-android/serialized-kbase) in devices with API level 21. But for all newer devices I am getting the error

```
dalvik.system.DexPathList is not accessible from MultiDexClassLoader
```

What is the solution for running drools on new phones?
I am using Android Studio Canary 9 to build the application for java 1.8 support.

My gradle depenedencies are as follows:

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile (group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-android', version: '6.5.0.Final') {
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j' , module: 'slf4j-api'
}
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2'
compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-3'
compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
```

Comment: I get an exception when using KieServices.Factory.get();. Do you have the same problem?